# Why is __init__ apparently optional?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While experimenting, I wrote:

```
class Bag:   
    pass

g = Bag()
print(g)
```

Which gave me:

```
<__main__.Bag object at 0x00000000036F0748>
```

Which surprised me. I expected an error when I tried to initialize it, since I didn't define `__init___`.

Why isn't this the case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only need to override the methods you want to change.

In other words:

If you don't override `__init__`, the `__init__` method of the superclass will be called.

E.g.

```
class Bag:
    pass
```

if equivalent to:

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bag, self).__init__()
```

Furthermore, `__init__` is indeed optional. It is an *initializer* for an **instance**.

When you instantiate a class (by calling it) the *constructor* for the **class** (class method `__new__`) is called. The constructor returns an instance for which `__init__` is called.

So in practice even:

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` is an intializer not the constructor, If an `__init__` method is defined it is used just to initialize the created object with the values provided as arguments. An object anyhow gets created even if an `__init__` method is not defined for the class, however not initialized, as `__init__` method is not overridden to customize as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to include the `__init__` method if you do not intend on adding/changing it's functionality. Everything in python is an object and python objects have a number of built in methods, some of which you may include when creating your own object and some of which you may not. This is not a bad reference for learning about built in methods.

http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html

I might add one thing. If you intend on using the `super` function, it is a good idea to define objects which inherit from `object`. Perhaps this is not required in python 3+ but it is certainly true for some of the older versions.

```
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Bag, self).__init__()
        # Adding extra functionality here.
```

Comment: Oops! Class name should be `Bag`. I was not having a dig. Sorry!

Comment: +/-0 - duplicate answer, but nice link.